# Does the image of a Cauchy sequence converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, cauchy-sequences

Let $V$ be a normed space and $W$ a Banach space. Given a bounded linear operator $A \in \mathcal L(V,W)$ and a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in $V$, does the image sequence, $\{Af_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, converge?
I have the following proof: since $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy, $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists N\in \mathbb N: 
\forall n, m \ge N:\|f_n-f_m\| < \frac\varepsilon{\|A\|}.$ So, we then have $$\|Af_n - Af_m\| =\|A(f_n -f_m)\| \le \|A\|\cdot\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon, $$ so that the sequence $\{Af_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is Cauchy in $W$. But, $W$ is a Banach space, so the sequence converges. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems kind of counter-intuitive at first, because the sequence in $V$ might not converge.

Comment: to take care of the case when $||A||=0$, use $\varepsilon/(||A||+1)$. otherwise looks good.

Comment: @CSquared I suppose I had implicitly assumed that$\|A\| \ne 0$. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: $A$ is linear and continuous, so it maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.  Of course with nonlinear continuous maps that may not be true.